# Creating Reports and Dashboards in a React Application with Spring Boot Backend

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, reporting, dashboard

I am new to the reporting world. I have fair amount of experience with React JS Applications and Spring Boot Backend. I am looking for help on integrating any reporting tool in my React Website so that it can show different data that I have stored in my database in MySQL. My backend is running on Spring Boot and my React App interacts with my database using spring boot rest calls.

I have heard about Jasper, Kibana and Pentaho. But do not have a clear view of which of these tools I can actually use and how will they interact with my React Web Page where I can let say give a menu option to users to go to Reports and then in that Reports page, there will be a list of predefined reports which if User clicks on them, then can see the results probably in a tabular format.

Any help/guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks